# Debugging "Injection of autowired dependencies failed" Error in Spring+Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have just started with Spring Framework and trying to develop and run a simple a app using Spring + Hibernate + Maven for dependency management.

I have a ContactController in which a property of type ContactService is Autowired. But when i packaged it into war and deployed on tomcat it throws a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException with following messages :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  
'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: 
An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping 
class="org.kodeplay.contact.form.Contact"/>
```

So I commented out that property from the ContactController Class along with all its references and re deployed it. But still it shows the same error.

This is the only controller in the entire application and an object implementing the ContactService interface is not being used any where else.

Whats going on here ? Am I missing something ?

Edit : Adding the code for spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.kodeplay.contact" /> 

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Internationalization -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <!-- To load database connection details from jdbc.properties file -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- To establish a connection to the database -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>org.kodeplay.contact.form.Contact</value>
        </list>
        </property>        
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>        
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

code for hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="org.kodeplay.contact.form.Contact" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: We'll need to see the Spring and Hibernate config definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this be a clash between `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` and `hibernate.cfg.xml`. If you're using the former, you shouldn't need the latter.  If you use both, you're going to have to duplicate some settings, and the `cfg` file might be eclipsing the Spring config.

Whatever you have in `hibernate.cfg.xml` you should be able to move into the bean definition for the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`, and that should resolve your error.

Comment: hi.. i removed the reference to the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the servlet config xml by removing the configLocation property now (please refer code in question). Still no help. Is there anything else to be added to the sessionFactory bean configuration in servlet xml? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you try to configure Hibernate with `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`. However, you use annotations in Hibernate mapping, therefore you need to use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` instead.

Comment: I was initially using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`. then I changed it to `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` and also added the list of annotatedClasses after reading but still no help. Thanks